# How do I move the position of the player based on user input. (Represented by O). Code I have written So far. Pls answer in vb

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Program
    Dim startx As Integer
    Dim starty As Integer
    Dim endx As Integer
    Dim endy As Integer
    Dim maze As String(,) = {
                {"x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x"},
                {"O ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "x ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "x ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x"},
                {"x ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "  ", "x"},
                {"x ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "  ", " "},
                {"x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x ", "x"}}
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("This is a maze game")
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter where you want to go (x and y cordinate)")
        start

        displaychessboard()

    End Sub
    Sub displaychessboard()
        Console.WriteLine("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
        For x As Integer = 0 To 9
            Console.Write(x & " ")
            For y As Integer = 0 To 9
                Console.Write(maze(x, y))

            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub makemove()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I move the position of the player based on user input.

You store the position of a player in one or more variables. Since you have a two-dimensional maze, you can use a two-element tuple or, for simplicity, a `player_x` and a `player_y` variable.

When the user provides input, you modify the variables accordingly. For example, "moving left" would decrease `player_x` by one.

When drawing your maze, you look at the current values of `player_x` and `player_y`. If they match the current position in your loop, you output "O" instead of a space.

> Pls answer in vb

The Stack Overflow community will gladly help you understand concepts and teach you how to improve your Visual Basic skills, but we are not a *"here is my task, you write code"* service.